# Attribute error with string trying to refer to a instance

Tags: python

I am getting this error
`AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'health'`
I think it is because the object I am trying to modify is a attribute of the instance, but when I refer to the instance I get user input that changes it to a string. How can I change it so that the string refers to the instance instead? I have looked at a post here but it was from 5 years ago and it seems outdated and didn't help.

so in the terminal it shows

```
Heal who? Rachel # I entered the Rachel part
```

which is from this part of the code

```
heal = input("Heal who? ")
Sidekick.heal(heal)
```

and it executes

```
    def heal(self,target):
        """Heals the target by 20 hp."""
        if self.level <= 5:
            restore = 20
        elif self.level <= 10:
            restore = 35
        elif self.level <= 15:
            restore = 50
        target.health += restore
        if target.health > target.full_health:
            restore = target.full_health - target.health
            target.health = target.full_health
        print("Healed " + target.name + " by " + str(restore) + " hp.")
```

Comment: Why did you think that the string `"Rachel"` has an attribute `health`? What did you expect `target` to be if not a string?

Comment: Do you have a variable called `Rachel` that you want to refer to? Then you should store it in a dictionary so that you can look it up by name.

Comment: @mkrieger1 I have an instance named Rachel

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I create a variable number of variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-a-variable-number-of-variables)

Comment: @mkrieger1 no, but your earlier suggestion to make a dictionary works! I made the string the key and the actual instance as the value and it works. Thank you!

Comment: What I just linked *is* the suggestion to use a dictionary.